# Angular 4 - Store data in localStorage when login is successful

Tags: angular

I have a login function and I want to store the data in localstorage only when the login is valid, but in my case, even the login is invalid it still store the data in localstorage.

**component**

```
 onSubmit = function(formData) {
   this._membersService.login(formData);
   localStorage.setItem('loginSessId', formData.acct_username);
 }
```

**service**

```
login(data) {
  return this._http.post('http://localhost/membership/main/login', data)
  .subscribe(data => data);
}
```

Comment: well where do you handle login failure? from this code, even if login fails, `localStorage.setItem()`seems to get executed;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to subscribe in the component, and there you can do it only when is successful like this:

**Component**

```
onSubmit = function(formData) {
  this._membersService.login(formData).subscribe((response) => {
    localStorage.setItem('loginSessId', formData.acct_username);
  },
    (err) => console.log(err)
  );
}
```

**service**

```
login(data) {
  return this._http.post('http://localhost/membership/main/login', data);
}
```

Comment: great, this works, I just added a condition when response.text() is success then the localstorage will execute

Comment: awesome, you can use httpClient instead of http to cast it so you have a json object in the subscribe's response, OR, use a map operator and return it as json (if you dont want to go through services changing for httpClient). Please upvote and accept to close the question.

Comment: I still donet have privilege to cast a vote yet. ahhh  my code is this  if(response.text() ) { //localStorage }, what is the best abd safest way?

Comment: now you do, im updating the service code from my response to show you how to make response a json()

Comment: which error you're getting? if you add map() to the service, response is a json, .text() wont work anymore.

Comment: i dont have error, it just dont work, any function inside subsribe are not working when I added map() in service

Comment: weird, it cant just "dont work" if you provide any other insight i can help you. in the meantime i've removed the map and revert it back to my original answer.